# Refactor subqueries using GROUP BY/HAVING?

Tags: sql, mysql, refactoring, query-optimization

I'm building a MySQL query to determine how many items from each of several categories appear in a given date range. My initial attempt looked like this:

```
select Title, 
  (select count(*) from entries where CategoryID=1
    and Date >= @StartDate and Date <= @EndDate) as Cat1,
  (select count(*) from entries where CategoryID=2
   and Date >= @StartDate and Date <= @EndDate) as Cat2,
  (select count(*) from entries where CategoryID is null
   and Date >= @StartDate and Date <= @EndDate) as UnkownCategory
from entries
  where Date >= @StartDate and Date <= @EndDate
```

The table is quite large and I'd like to refactor the query to speed it up, but I'm not sure how - can this be rewritten using GROUP BY/HAVING statements or is there another way I'm missing?

**Edit**: Sample result set - something like this:

```
Title | Category 1 Total | Category 2 Total | Unknown Category Total
ABC     1                  3                  0
DEF     2                  7                  2
```

Comment: Can you provide an example resultset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select Title, SUM(CategoryID=1) as Cat1, SUM(categoryID=2) as Cat2,
SUM(categoryID IS NULL) as UnknownCategory
FROM entries
WHERE Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY Title
```

You can stick expressions in sum() functions: truth equals 1, false equals 0. Also I used the BETWEEN operator which is a little faster.

An alternative that would return a different result layout but is a little conceptually simpler:

```
select Title, CategoryID, count(*)
from entries
WHERE Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
group by Title, CategoryID
```

Comment: Thanks the format on this is perfect and won't require changes to the report generation. It also seems quite fast.

Comment: Yes, the second solution is what rikh suggested. I'm sticking with the SUM version though as long as it's fast enough since its format is easier to handle. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select COUNT(*), sTitle, CategoryID FROM entries 
WHERE Date >= @StartDate and Date <= @EndDate 
GROUP BY CategoryID, sTitle
```

Comment: Better add the CategoryID to the result set!

Comment: Thanks! I actually need the count per entry though, but I think a slight modification works: 

Select count(*), sTitle, CategoryID FROM entries where Date >= @StartDate and Date <= @EndDate GROUP BY CategoryID, sTitle

Answer (score 0):

How about grouping by category id then using the having statement to filter out specific categories, like:

```
select CategoryID, count(*) 
from entries 
where Date >= @StartDate AND Date <= @EndDate
group by CategoryID
having CategoryID = 1 or CategoryID = 2 or CategoryID is null
```

If there are multiple titles per category you could group by both fields:

```
select Title, CategoryID, count(*) 
from entries 
where Date >= @StartDate AND Date <= @EndDate
group by Title, CategoryID
having CategoryID = 1 or CategoryID = 2 or CategoryID is null
```

Comment: Put the categoryID conditions in the where clause, not the having clause.